# Django, ImportError: cannot import name 'task' from 'celery'

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I have Django application that was using Celery version 4.4.2, which was working fine.

```
from celery import task
import logging


@task(ignore_result=True)
def log_user_activity(user_id):
    try:
        logging.info(user_id)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
```

As I tried to update the Celery version to v5.2.2 I get below error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'task' from 'celery'

Can someone help what is task been replaced with?
they still have example here with same.
https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.2.2/examples/celery_http_gateway/tasks.py

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This API was deprecated, and then [removed in 5.0](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/internals/deprecation.html).

That page suggests to change

```
from celery import task
```

into

```
from celery import shared_task
```

There are other changes as well which don't apply to the snippet you've posted but may apply to the rest of your code. See that page (and the rest of the documentation, especially the [Upgrading from Celery 4.x](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/whatsnew-5.2.html#upgrading-from-celery-4-x) section) for more details.

Comment: There were lots of other dependent packages that were needed to update too. Which lead to some errors. So it was confusing the error were related to celery or other packages. But solved them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some older things are deprecated in Celery 5.0 and The latest version of the celery is working fine and most of the new things are added in the new version. **Recommended**: you need to use the latest version of the celery.

celery.py

```
from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'pj_name.settings')
app = Celery('pj_name')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

after that go under the app/tasks.py and add your first scheduler function.

```
from pj_name.celery import app
@app.task
def first_task():
    pass
```

the above code block is worked if you are using celery latest version.